# Changing the popup position on the Leaflet marker on the left side Page?

Tags: css, popup, leaflet, styles

I want that when I click on a point in leaflet my popup opens on the left side. How can I do it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/57zfZ.jpg .also
I change style leaflet css file   like this :

I change this part :

```
.leaflet-popup {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    }



  to: 

 .leaflet-popup {

position:absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    }
```

But not working!!

Comment: Have you used your browser's dev tools to inspect the styles on the popup and see where the position is coming from?

Answer (score 3):

I enter new style in my HTML and done!.

```
 [Codepen]: https://codepen.io/stackoverflowcom/pen/OJJwooE/ "view on Codepen"
```